# cannot connect back to sql server authentication

Tags: sql-server

I was using sql server authentication for my local pc database but then I set it to window authentication and restart the database . After that, I can't login the sql server authentication with the correct user and password . how to set it back to default ?

was using microsoft sql server 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the registry key, here is a quick guide: http://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/08/15/change-authentication-mode-from-windows-registry/

Once changed, you'll need to restart the instance.

Comment: what if my sql server is 2012, there is no guide

Comment: It's the same registry key in the same spot as 2008.